# Compilers that support C11

Tags: c, compiler-construction, c11

I was wondering if there are any compilers that support a considerable amount of the new C11 standard. Looking for features like Generic Selection etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: not a direct answer because not a compiler but P99, http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__C11.html, is able to emulate most features of C11 quite well, best working on the intersection of gcc family of compilers (in a broad sense) and POSIX systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pelles C version 7.00 (Release Candidate is available now)

http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/

Comment: @IntermediateHacker Yes, see _Generic selection_ entry in the help file.

Comment: 7.00 was released on Jul 08, 2012

Comment: maybe worth noting, ms-windows only.

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is probably Clang. See the release notes for [the current release](http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/docs/ClangReleaseNotes.html#cchanges) and [the upcoming one](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#cchanges).

Answer (score 6):

GCC 4.9 supports generic selection . It is in general bugfixing stage before release. http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html

Answer (score 5):

I think [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#c_generic_selections) supports generic selection.

Answer (score 0):

Intel 18 supports nearly all of C11 and supported generic selection starting in version 16.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c11-support-in-intel-c-compiler

Cray 8.5 documents support for C11 [here](https://pubs.cray.com/content/S-2179/8.5/cray-c-and-c++-reference-manual-85/the-cray-compiling-environment) but I haven't tested it thoroughly.  I recall that atomics have been supported for a while, because they are necessary for [this project](https://github.com/ofiwg/libfabric) to work on Cray machines.

Full disclosure: I work for Intel, but not in the compiler team.